# How can I use iCloud to synchronize a .zip file between my apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, zip, ios5, icloud

Is it possible to upload a `.zip` file to `iCloud`, and then have it be synchronized across all of a user's iOS devices?
If so, how would I go about doing this?
If there is any File size limit, then also mention max. file size allowed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is how I synchronized zip files with iCloud .

Steps:

1) http://transoceanic.blogspot.in/2011/07/compressuncompress-files-on.html
    . Refer this link to download zip api which is having code for  zipping and unzipping folder.

2) Now all you need to play with NSData.

3) "MyDocument.h" file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyDocument : UIDocument
    @property (strong) NSData *zipDataContent;
@end
```

4)

```
#import "MyDocument.h"

@implementation MyDocument
@synthesize zipDataContent;

// Called whenever the application reads data from the file system
- (BOOL)loadFromContents:(id)contents ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    self.zipDataContent = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:[contents bytes] length:[contents length]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"noteModified" object:self];
    return YES;     
}

// Called whenever the application (auto)saves the content of a note
- (id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError 
{
    return self.zipDataContent;
}

@end
```

5) Now somewhere in your app you need to zip folder and sync with icloud.

```
-(BOOL)zipFolder:(NSString *)toCompress zipFilePath:(NSString *)zipFilePath
{
    BOOL isDir=NO;

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pathToCompress = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:toCompress];

    NSArray *subpaths;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathToCompress isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir){
        subpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:pathToCompress];
    } else if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathToCompress]) {
        subpaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:pathToCompress];
    }

    zipFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:zipFilePath];
    //NSLog(@"%@",zipFilePath);
    ZipArchive *za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    [za CreateZipFile2:zipFilePath];
    if (isDir) {
        for(NSString *path in subpaths){  
            NSString *fullPath = [pathToCompress stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
            if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir){
                [za addFileToZip:fullPath newname:path];  
            }
        }
    } else {
        [za addFileToZip:pathToCompress newname:toCompress];
    }

    BOOL successCompressing = [za CloseZipFile2];
    if(successCompressing)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
-(IBAction) iCloudSyncing:(id)sender  
{
    //***** PARSE ZIP FILE : Pictures *****
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    if([self zipFolder:@"Pictures" zipFilePath:@"iCloudPictures"])
        NSLog(@"Picture Folder is zipped");

    ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]  URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"iCloudPictures.zip"];

    mydoc = [[MyDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];
    NSString *zipFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iCloudPictures"];
    NSURL *u = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:zipFilePath];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:u];
    // NSLog(@"%@ %@",zipFilePath,data);
    mydoc.zipDataContent = data;

    [mydoc saveToURL:[mydoc fileURL] forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) 
    {
        if (success) 
        {
            NSLog(@"PictureZip: Synced with icloud");
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"PictureZip: Syncing FAILED with icloud");

    }];
}
```

6) You can unzip data received from iCloud like this.

```
- (void)loadData:(NSMetadataQuery *)queryData {



    for (NSMetadataItem *item in [queryData results]) 
    {    
        NSString *filename = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemDisplayNameKey];


        NSURL *url = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];
        MyDocument *doc = [[MyDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

if([filename isEqualToString:@"iCloudPictures"])
        {
            [doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                if (success) {
                    NSLog(@"Pictures : Success to open from iCloud");
                    NSData *file = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

                    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSString *zipFolder = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Pics.zip"];
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:zipFolder contents:file attributes:nil];
                    //NSLog(@"zipFilePath : %@",zipFolder);

                    NSString *outputFolder = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Pictures"];//iCloudPics
                    ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
                    if( [za UnzipOpenFile: zipFolder] ) {
                        if( [za UnzipFileTo:outputFolder overWrite:YES] != NO ) {
                            NSLog(@"Pics : unzip successfully");
                          }
                        [za UnzipCloseFile];
                    }
                    [za release];


                    NSError *err;
                    NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:outputFolder error:&err];
                    if (files == nil) {
                        NSLog(@"EMPTY Folder: %@",outputFolder);
                    }
                    // Add all sbzs to a list    
                    for (NSString *file in files) {
                        //if ([file.pathExtension compare:@".jpeg" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {        
                        NSLog(@" Pictures %@",file);

                        //                            NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                        //                            NSDictionary *attributes = [fm fileAttributesAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,file]                                                                 traverseLink:NO];
                        //                            
                        //                            NSNumber* fileSize = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
                        //                            int e = [fileSize intValue]; //Size in bytes
                        //                            NSLog(@"%@__%d",file,e);           
                    }

                }
                else 
                {
                    NSLog(@"Pictures : failed to open from iCloud");
                    [self hideProcessingView];
                }
            }]; 
        }
}
}
```

Comment: I want to ask you suppose I create a zip folder and syned it with iCloud and when data comes from icloud so , that folder will be unziped to its same location or I need to manually add every files containing in that folder to my documents folder.

Comment: You can keep same document folder when you unzip it.i did the same.here NSString *outputFolder = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Pictures"]; in this line "Pictures" is my document directory folder.You can see "Pictures" at  if([self zipFolder:@"Pictures" zipFilePath:@"iCloudPictures"]) while zipping also.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I helps me a lot in understanding the code and it works like a charm for me.I wish I could vote so many times.Thanks again.

Comment: my pleasure. i need to find a way for syncing sqlite database which is having text,pictures and audios. so desparately i find this way of doing it. thanx. :) :)

Comment: I also posted a question on this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408695/how-to-use-icloud-for-syncing-my-sqlite-database-and-images-that-resides-in-the is the link of the question.Please give the answer as link of this page so that I can accept and vote up there also.

Comment: Do you think it might be better to put the zipping and unzipping right inside the UIDocument subclass? I'm contemplating doing that for my UIDocument subclass now.

Comment: Better u can create other class and put those methods in that class as we are inheriting UIDocument.

Comment: Hello Bhargavi. I want to ask a small doubt in the above process..  can you please explain where to use the unzipping method  because if i give that method to a button action. The program crashes at the first if loop [query results]. Please help me out on this issue.It is showing error as : [UIRoundedRectButton results]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c998e0
  Thanks

Comment: Hi krishna what i feel is you should put unzipping code on and other rest method for cloud in AppDelegate > didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. This is the best way to get all data back. Do not need to give and button. Please let me know if this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: what i have is sqlite file in the documents folder and i am trying to put that in iCLoud and want to get that back when required. I have a button action syncToiCloudaction in which i am puttin the code for the zipping process an its method.  and i have another button  " Downloadfromicloud button".when i press this buttton i want my data to be retrieved to the same folder. could you please share a sample which would help me a ton.          ThankYOu

Comment: Hello Bhargavi. My name is Rajkumar. I am new to stack overflow so i could not comment to the above post. that is why i have asked the questions from my friends account i.e Krishna Prasad. I have given my mailid above. please forward the code to the above mail id.    Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Hi Bhargavi. i am really sorry to disturb you. please oblige and revert back.      thanks rajkumar

Comment: Hello Bhargavi. i have implemented the following code you sent me. it is syncing with icloud as the log says and getting data from icloud. Could you pleae help me with how this all works. I mean where to check if the data is being posted or stored.

Comment: hi @Bhargavi .. i need this code .. if you can help me .. plz send it to mah id : rockyrakesh.p@gmail.com ..

Comment: this one is same code(as above) i used for zip. You can use same :)

Comment: @Bhargavi hey do you know how to get synchronized data from iCloud and restore it.?

Comment: I am saving data in .csv file format @Bhargavi .Is it the correct way to save the data in that format???? Or else should i follow the method which yo had mentioned.Actually my requirement is to save data in Icloud and restore data in any file format.

Answer (score 2):

In order to enabling Document storage in **iCloud** your "document" needs to be encapsulated in a [UIDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocument_Class/UIDocument/UIDocument.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDocument) object.

Because `UIDocument` links to a file URL, you can easily create a `UIDocument` pointing to `file://myzipfile.zip` and then upload a zip document to **iCloud**.

I hope this helps

Comment: Hello iGranDev, i have seen this document but didn't get too much help from this documentation, will you please give me some piece of code to understand more. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Actually, you don't need UIDocument to share documents on iCloud. NSFileManager will let you upload documents manually, without ever touching UIDocument. I wrote a walkthrough about this [here](http://samvermette.com/312).

Comment: Indeed ! Thanks a lot for this walkthrough. I've just tweet it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this tutorial can help you more:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1