# Syncing sqlite database with iCloud

Tags: ios5

I have my sqlite database. now i want syncing with icloud. I read blogs saying sqlite syncing with icloud is not supported. Either go for core data OR "Do what exactly core data does".

Now it is not posible for me to go for core data.So like second option "Do something similar to how CoreData syncs sqlite DBs: send "transaction logs" to iCloud instead and build each local sqlite file off of those."

please can anyone share any sample code for "transaction log" of sqlite OR can expalin in detail stepwise what i need to do?

Comment: Can u plz tell me that we have to create XML every time? or update with changes only in that XML? If only changes then plz let me know how? or if create XML then I think this will be time consuming operation.. Please suggest..

Comment: If you are flexible enough for making changes in existing XML then it would be great. And of course you can modify existing one. :) no need to create every time

Comment: Can u plz let me know how to make changes in existing one?

Comment: I have not made any changes in existing one. But you need to work around for this i guess. As in my case i was creating XML every time as there is need of bulk change. If you are having key-pair value type data then u can also go for plist file.

Comment: @βhargavḯ I read in one of your question that you want to accpet credit card in one of your app. I want your help for same. Did you complete that task? And yes then ...did apple approve it?

Comment: @vivek answer for that question is given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873376/credit-card-payment-api-in-iphone-without-terminal. I have tried for zooz. But then I didn't integrate within app. I am not sure for AppStore Approval.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) I followed this link to create xml. You can download respective api from its github.Link is - http://arashpayan.com/blog/2009/01/14/apxml-nsxmldocument-substitute-for-iphoneipod-touch/

2) on button click:

```
-(IBAction) btniCloudPressed:(id)sender
{
    // create the document with it’s root element
    APDocument *doc = [[APDocument alloc] initWithRootElement:[APElement elementWithName:@"Properties"]];
    APElement *rootElement = [doc rootElement]; // retrieves same element we created the line above

    NSMutableArray *addrList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *select_query;
    const char *select_stmt;
    sqlite3_stmt *compiled_stmt;
    if (sqlite3_open([[app getDBPath] UTF8String], &dbconn) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        select_query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Properties"];
        select_stmt = [select_query UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbconn, select_stmt, -1, &compiled_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiled_stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                NSString *addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,0)]];
                addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%@",addr,[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,1)]];
                addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%@",addr,[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,2)]];
                addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%@",addr,[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,3)]];
                addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%@",addr,[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,4)]];
                addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%@",addr,[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,5)]];
                addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%@",addr,[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,6)]];
                addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%@",addr,[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,7)]];

                //NSLog(@"%@",addr);
                [addrList addObject:addr];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiled_stmt);
        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"Error while creating detail view statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(dbconn));
        }

    }

    for(int i =0 ; i < [addrList count]; i++)
    {
        NSArray *addr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[addrList objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"]];

        APElement *property = [APElement elementWithName:@"Property"];
        [property addAttributeNamed:@"id" withValue:[addr objectAtIndex:0]];
        [property addAttributeNamed:@"street" withValue:[addr objectAtIndex:1]];
        [property addAttributeNamed:@"city" withValue:[addr objectAtIndex:2]];
        [property addAttributeNamed:@"state" withValue:[addr objectAtIndex:3]];
        [property addAttributeNamed:@"zip" withValue:[addr objectAtIndex:4]];
        [property addAttributeNamed:@"status" withValue:[addr objectAtIndex:5]];
        [property addAttributeNamed:@"lastupdated" withValue:[addr objectAtIndex:6]];
        [property addAttributeNamed:@"deleted" withValue:[addr objectAtIndex:7]];
        [rootElement addChild:property];
        [property release];

        APElement *fullscore = [APElement elementWithName:@"FullScoreReport"];
        [property addChild:fullscore];
        [fullscore release];
        select_query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT AnsNo,Answer,AnswerScore,MaxScore,AnsIndex FROM FullScoreReport WHERE Addr_ID = %@",[addr objectAtIndex:0]];
        select_stmt = [select_query UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbconn, select_stmt, -1, &compiled_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiled_stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                APElement *answer = [APElement elementWithName:@"Answer"];
                [answer addAttributeNamed:@"AnsNo" withValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,0)]]];
                [answer addAttributeNamed:@"Answer" withValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,1)]]];
                [answer addAttributeNamed:@"AnswerScore" withValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,2)]]];
                [answer addAttributeNamed:@"MaxScore" withValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,3)]]];
                [answer addAttributeNamed:@"AnsIndex" withValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiled_stmt,4)]]];
                [fullscore addChild:answer];
                [answer release];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiled_stmt);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(dbconn);


    NSString *prettyXML = [doc prettyXML];
    NSLog(@"\n\n%@",prettyXML);


    //***** PARSE XML FILE *****
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Properties.xml" ];
    NSData *file = [NSData dataWithBytes:[prettyXML UTF8String] length:strlen([prettyXML UTF8String])];
    [file writeToFile:path atomically:YES];


    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Properties.xml"];
    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]  URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];


    MyDocument *mydoc = [[MyDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];
    mydoc.xmlContent = prettyXML;
    [mydoc saveToURL:[mydoc fileURL]forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) 
     {

         if (success) 
         {
             NSLog(@"XML: Synced with icloud");
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iCloud Syncing" message:@"Successfully synced with iCloud." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
             [alert release];



         }
         else
             NSLog(@"XML: Syncing FAILED with icloud");


     }];

}
```

3)MyDocument.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyDocument : UIDocument
    @property (strong) NSString *xmlContent;
@end
```

4)MyDocument.m file

```
#import "MyDocument.h"

@implementation MyDocument
@synthesize xmlContent,zipDataContent;

// Called whenever the application reads data from the file system
- (BOOL)loadFromContents:(id)contents ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    // NSLog(@"* ---> typename: %@",typeName);
                self.xmlContent = [[NSString alloc] 
                               initWithBytes:[contents bytes] 
                               length:[contents length] 
                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"noteModified" object:self];
    return YES;     
}

// Called whenever the application (auto)saves the content of a note
- (id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError 
{

        return [NSData dataWithBytes:[self.xmlContent UTF8String] length:[self.xmlContent length]];

}

@end
```

5) now in ur appdelegate

```
- (void)loadData:(NSMetadataQuery *)queryData
 {


    for (NSMetadataItem *item in [queryData results]) 
    {    
        NSString *filename = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemDisplayNameKey];
        NSNumber *filesize = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemFSSizeKey]; 
        NSDate *updated = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemFSContentChangeDateKey];
        NSLog(@"%@ (%@ bytes, updated %@) ", filename, filesize, updated);

        NSURL *url = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];
        MyDocument *doc = [[MyDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
        if([filename isEqualToString:@"Properties"])
        {
            [doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                if (success) {
                    NSLog(@"XML: Success to open from iCloud");
                    NSData *file = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                    //NSString *xmlFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:file encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                    //NSLog(@"%@",xmlFile);

                    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:file];
                    [parser setDelegate:self];
                    [parser parse];
                    //We hold here until the parser finishes execution
                    [parser release];
                }
                else 
                {
                    NSLog(@"XML: failed to open from iCloud");
                 }
            }]; 
        }
}
}
```

6) now in parser method fetch data and insert/update as needed in database.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)nameSpaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
if ([elementName isEqual:@"Property"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Property attributes : %@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"],[attributeDict objectForKey:@"street"], [attributeDict objectForKey:@"city"], [attributeDict objectForKey:@"state"],[attributeDict objectForKey:@"zip"],[attributeDict objectForKey:@"status"],[attributeDict objectForKey:@"lastupdated"],[attributeDict objectForKey:@"deleted"]);
}
//like this way fetch all data and insert in db
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.I just want to ask can I send image also on iCloud.

Comment: Yes i did for images also (say folder of pictures). i have answered for same at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047217/how-can-i-use-icloud-to-synchronize-a-zip-file-between-my-apps/10069242#10069242

Comment: I integrated the above code it works well now but I want to ask how it manages if I changes some thing in my entry.

Comment: Will you please elaborate your statement? basically entry in database is managed at your end. Now you are simply creating xml of existing changed database and sending it to cloud.

Comment: yes, I want to know suppose I created an entry and sync it with iCloud, then I made some changes in that entry how will it be synced on icloud because there is only one xml file.Do I need to replace the xml file on icloud with newly craeted file which include changes made in entry.

Comment: yes as we are not using coredata. So for each and every small change u need to replace xml on cloud. u can place this process in background also.

Comment: Can you please help me how to sync the images on icloud.It would be a great help to me.Thanks for you code.It really helps me a lot.

Comment: if you want to upload multiple file plz c my this answer.You can create zip of your images and sync zip file to cloud http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047217/how-can-i-use-icloud-to-synchronize-a-zip-file-between-my-apps/10069242#10069242

Comment: @Bhargavi so to save in icloud we can to convert sqlite to xml?

Comment: @Bhargavi here you are sending sqlite and again for folder you are sending it by  converting it into zipfile sp why cant you send sqlite also in same way by taking sqlite in a folder in your project by getting path?

Comment: @ganeshmanoj Yes you can give it a try. It will work. :) Initially I wanted to send "transaction logs" to iCloud like core data so I put efforts on this way.

Comment: @Bhargavi YOur code is very useful for me and i will try like that also

Comment: @Bhargavi Is this possible can i Convert Sqlite to NSData and upload on icloud rather then XML....

Comment: @SureshJagnani Hopefully yes. I have not tried it yet. You can give it a try :)

Comment: @Bhargavi  HI.. Yes thanks a lot for your answer. I just want to know how can i upload and download from icloud. thanks a lot for your help. Actually i using Dox tutorial of icloud. there is many methods but in your code i see its too easy.. Just clear me only which methods required for upload and which is for download.

Comment: @SureshJagnani 5 & 6 will handle download , rest for upload.

Comment: Thanks a lot Awesome help. I already do like that.. Just small thing here.Download is well just issue in upload
NSString *strFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.sqlite",basePath];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strFile];
   NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test.sqlite"];
NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]
                              URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

Comment: Note *doc = [[Note alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];
   *** doc.noteContent = data***;
[doc saveToURL:[doc fileURL] forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {if (success) { NSLog(@"Synced with icloud");}}];

Comment: @Bhargavi issue is that how can i assign doc.noteContent = data. thanks a lot for your kind response..

Comment: @SureshJagnani Can you please post separate question and post code there? It's not worth to write it here and also not readable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29594/discussion-between-suresh-jagnani-and-bhargavi)

Comment: Thanks for this info.. I am stuck at a problem though.. Can you please look into following issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16580906/443292

Comment: @Shri I have tried Second option from given link that is the way I have implemented here and I got my app approved. Only point to note is  do this sync in background , do not give any UI element to sync with iCloud

Comment: I have also implemented syncing but data is not updating properly.
i am facing this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821872/sqlite-sync-with-icloud-not-updating-data
can you help me in this