# Credit card payment api in iPhone without terminal

Tags: iphone, ios, credit-card

I want to integrate Credit Card payment functionality which collects information from user like credit card payment details, process, pay & receive receipt for payment in iphone app. Please not that this functionality needs to be implemented without using "Credit Card payment Terminal". Please suggest something/api/sample code on this. Despite the fact that In-app-purchase is recommended, does apple approve this kind of payment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For in-app purchases we have 3 options

[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html) in-app purchase (requires apple account)

[PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_login-done&login_access=0) payment gateway (requires Paypal account)

[Zooz](http://www.zooz.com/#) payment gateway (requires Credit/Debit card info)

All the 3 are approved by apple, for your need you can opt for third one, and even it supports Paypal with in that if user want s to pay through his Paypal account.