# Core Data with icloud in IOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data, icloud

Is it possible to build an application using core data with iCloud Feature for IOS 5 Deployment? If any Please Provide me some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953345/syncing-sqlite-database-with-icloud) is the solution to sync your core data with iCloud. you can use this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) for how the `iCloud` sync works. But you need to scratch little bit to get it work