# Sqlite sync with iCloud not updating data

Tags: ios, sqlite, icloud

I am using `iCloud` for sqlite database sync between multiple devices.
i have implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953345/syncing-sqlite-database-with-icloud) functionality in my app for sqlite sync.

But data is updating after 5 mins on other devices.
is this problem from iCloud side because as far as i know we cannot manually update iCloud.

i know it is not correct to use sqlite for icloud sync but i have more 100 tables and i cannot migrate to core data.

Please find my code below:

```
 AppDelegate.m
        [self checkForiCloudAccess];
        [[sqlmessenger shared] fireQueryForCloudData];
```

**Check for iCloud Access**

```
-(void)checkForiCloudAccess{
NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
if (ubiq) {
    NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq);
    isCloudAccees= TRUE;
    }
    else {

        isCloudAccees= FALSE;
    UIAlertView *alertb = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No iCloud acces" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertb show];
    }
}
```

sqlmessenger.m

**Fire Query to get iCloud Data**

```
- (void)fireQueryForCloudData{

    NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
    [query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K ENDSWITH '.xml'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];

    [query setPredicate:pred];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];

    [query startQuery];

}

- (void)queryDidFinishGathering:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSMetadataQuery *que = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc]init];
    que = [notification object];
    [que disableUpdates];
    [que stopQuery];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
                                                  object:que];

    self.metaQuery = que;
    que = nil;

    UIAlertView *alrView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Cloud updated" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];

    [alrView show];

    //TODO: Comment this stupid method
    //[self fetcLargeTableFromCloud];

}
```

**Update database using Metadata query object**

```
 - (void)loadData:(NSString *)tableName {
        _TblName = tableName;

            for (NSMetadataItem *item in [self.metaQuery results])
            {
                NSString *filename = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemDisplayNameKey];

                if([filename isEqualToString:tableName])
                {
                    NSURL *url = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];

                    //Conflict resolve

                    //[fileVersion replaceItemAtURL:url options:0 error:nil];


                    NSData *file = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

                    [NSFileVersion removeOtherVersionsOfItemAtURL:url error:nil];


                    NSArray *conflicts = [NSFileVersion unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL:url];

                    for (NSFileVersion *conflict in conflicts)
                    {
                        conflict.resolved = YES;

                        NSLog(@"conflict %@",conflict);
                    }


                    if (file) {
                        _arrCloudData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                        _tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


                        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:file];
                        [parser setDelegate:self];
                        [parser parse];


                        if (_arrCloudData.count !=0) {


                    [self deleteTable:tableName];


                    _arrColumnList = [self getColumnsForTable:tableName];
                            //[_arrColumnList removeObjectAtIndex:3];

                           // [_arrColumnList removeObjectAtIndex:5];
                           // [_arrColumnList removeObjectAtIndex:8];

                    NSString *columnNames = [_arrColumnList componentsJoinedByString:@","];
                     /*
                    NSMutableArray *arrtmp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_arrColumnList];

                    for (int i = 0; i<[arrtmp count]; i++) {
                        [arrtmp replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"?"];
                    }*/
                   // NSString *blidString = [arrtmp componentsJoinedByString:@","];

                    //TODO: Uncomment this lines
                    //NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into %@ (%@) values (%@)",tableName,columnNames,blidString];

                    //TODO: comment this line
                    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into %@ (%@) values",tableName,columnNames];


                           // NSDate *parseFinish = [NSDate date];
                        //[self insertRowIntblMealDetails:tableName :query];

                        int exCount = _arrCloudData.count/500;
                        for (int i=0; i<=exCount; i++) {
                            if ([tableName isEqualToString:@"tblRecipeSubtypes"]) {
                            [self insertRowIntblMealDetails:tableName :query:i];
                            }
                            else{
                                [self insertRowIntbl:tableName :query :i];
                            }


                        }
                        /*
                            for (int i=0; i<[_arrCloudData count]; i++) {

                                //Genralized method
                                //[self insertRowInTableName:tableName:i:query];
                                //
                                //[self insertRowIntblMealDetails:tableName :i :query];
                                [self insertRowIntblMealDetails:tableName :query];

                        }*/
                    sqlite3_close(database);
                    /*
                    NSDate *Complete = [NSDate date];


                    NSTimeInterval PraseComplete = [parseFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
                    NSTimeInterval LoopTime = [Complete timeIntervalSinceDate:parseFinish];
                    NSTimeInterval totalTime = [Complete timeIntervalSinceDate:start];


                    NSLog(@"Parse Execution Time: %f", PraseComplete);
                    NSLog(@"Loop Execution Time: %f", LoopTime);
                    NSLog(@"Total Execution Time: %@ %f ",tableName, totalTime);
                     */
                }
                        else{
                            NSLog(@"Empty Array %@",tableName);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        NSLog(@"Blank File %@",tableName);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

i call `loaddata` from respective classes to update database.
is there anyway with that i can update data early/fast or is there any problem in my code?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you making sure the file has been downloaded from iCloud before you try opening it?  Not sure if iOS8 iCloud file handling is different from iOS7 but usually you need to use a file coordinator and you may need to trigger the file download.  It looks like you are trying to use the URL directly without first checking the download state and without using a file coordinator for the read.  Better check this as I just had a quick glance at what you have done.

Comment: Where should i put that code?

Comment: Oh boy, I suggest you look at the examples here, its complicated:
http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Comment: I suggest you save yourself, what, 3 months of development time and just use parse.com  :/