# iCloud syncing app document folder

Tags: ios, icloud

I have an application that is basically a PDF reader. When PDF files are imported they are saved into the apps document folder.

My question is what is the best approach for syncing these files to iCloud for back up or use on other devices?

I've been reading a bit about `UIDocument` but I am struggling on how to use this along with PDF's as most tutorials just show a `NSString` as an example.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can zip all your files and you can sync it with `iCloud`. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047217/how-can-i-use-icloud-to-synchronize-a-zip-file-between-my-apps) is the answer you are looking for, and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) is the tutorial for `iCloud`. If you look onto the answer and follow the tutorial, surely you can make it work.